# How to get GCP Audit Log status programmatically

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to get a list of Audit Logs similar to what is displayed in Google console page (IAM/Audit Logs) using the Golang API `GetIamPolicy` as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy

If one service has at least one of its Log Types set (Data Read, Data Write or Admin Read), `GetIamPolicy` will return it, but if it does not have any set then the service is omitted from the response.

As an example, if my project has three services A, B and C and A has Data Read enabled, B has Admin Read enabled and C doesn't have anything enabled, `GetIamPolicy` will only return A and B.

`GetIamPolicyRequest` struct seems to have fields designed for this scenario (`NullFields` and `ForceSendFields`), but I couldn't make it work. Example:

```
    rb := &cloudresourcemanager.GetIamPolicyRequest{}
    rb.ForceSendFields = []string{"LogType"}
    rb.NullFields = []string{"LogType"}
    policyOptions := &cloudresourcemanager.GetPolicyOptions{}
    policyOptions.ForceSendFields = []string{"LogType"}
    policyOptions.NullFields = []string{"LogType"}
    policyOptions.RequestedPolicyVersion = 3
    rb.Options = policyOptions
```

Any ideas on how to retrieve the missing services?

Comment: I ran the console in Chrome and looked at the REST calls that were made.  I found that the following was made early ... 

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/iamPolicies/queryAuditableServices

What this returns is a list of the services for which auditing is possible.  Thinking this through ... if we now know which services CAN have auditing enabled then if we ask which services DO have auditing enabled ... we now have ALL the information we need.  In your example, you will get data for A and B but none for C but you WILL know that C CAN have auditing

Comment: @Kolban, I've done that too, but the numbers don't add up. The first API returns around 90 services, while I have 30 and only 4 are missing when compared to IAM/Audit Logs.

Comment: If it were me, I'd write up a detailed Google Doc and make it public showing the APIs I am calling, the results returned and analysis of those results and what the concerns may be.  I do not for one minute discount your report but anything you can do to make the examination and thinking easier for potential responders will really help.

Comment: Additionally to what Kolban said, I would recommend you to raise a bug to GCP in order for them to review the client library, as well as point out which APIs are the ones that you are missing so that you can provide more information.